# Google App Engine - Does HttpSessionListener work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I've found this post regarding the fact that you cannot use HttpSessionListener ([Google App Engine how to track httpsession destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809882/google-app-engine-how-to-track-httpsession-destroy)).

I would like to know if there's any change, if I can track when a session is opened or destroyed in Java, on Google App engine.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason why this didn't work is that there is no single VM to call this method on. This is still true. The architecture of App Engine doesn't really let you to that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine how to track httpsession destroy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809882/google-app-engine-how-to-track-httpsession-destroy)